# Let's have pyspark tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Some time we need to distinguish the question for **PySpark** from `spark` or `apache-spark`, so there should be a separate tag `pypsark` or `PySpark`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that we need to have a [pyspark](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyspark) tag. Users with 150 rep can already [create tags](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

So, I have created one and would edit the questions accordingly. You can also help by identifying appropriate questions and sending in edit requests.

Thanks for contributing.

Comment: Thanks for adding the tag, it will help lots of people, will definitely help in identifying the appropriate questions.